# Which of these 2 Video Cards are better for Blender?

Tags: modeling, rendering, gpu

I am new to blender and I need a video card for my computer, I only have two affordable options

1. nVidia GEFORCE GT 730 4GB DDR3 128BIT
2. nVidia PNY QUADRO T400, 2GB, GDDR6, 64-BIT

I am not a gamer, which one of these cards is better for modeling, animating, and rendering 3D in blender?

Comment: It is more of a hardware issue than a Blender problem.  I will say this:  the video card does make a difference in your work flow in terms of time, especially with rendering.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell using [userbenchmark](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-T400-vs-Nvidia-GeForce-GT-730/m1607441vsm12582), the T400 blows the GT 730 out of the water. And that makes sense, it’s much newer and also designed for workbench use.

For that reason I would recommend you use the T400, it should suit your needs much better than the GT 730